# Searching words in selected area

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to search specific words in the selected/highlighted text. The result should show how much the word is used throughout the highlighted selected area.

I wrote a macro, but the total value of words shown is calculated through the entire document, not the selected part.

```vb
Sub CountWords()
'macros for counting specific words in the document 
'to count the number of a specified word, this word needs to be highlighted 
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sWord As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sWord As String

    Set rng = Selection.Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sWord = InputBox( _
        Prompt:="What word do you want to count?", _
        Title:="Count Words", Default:="")
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = sWord
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        Do While .Execute
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With
    Select Case i
        Case 2 To 4
            MsgBox "word " & Chr(171) & sWord & Chr(187) & " occurred in the document " & i & " times", _
              vbInformation, "word count"
        Case 1
            MsgBox "word " & Chr(171) & sWord & Chr(187) & " occurred in the document " & i & " times", _
              vbInformation, "word count"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "word " & Chr(171) & sWord & Chr(187) & " occurred in the document " & i & " times", _
              vbInformation, "word count"
    End Select
    rng.Find.Text = ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff, even other peoples codes.  Every one of them counts specific words throughout the *entire* document.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, sWord As String, i As Long
sWord = InputBox(Prompt:="What word do you want to count?", Title:="Count Words", Default:="")
With Selection
  Set Rng = .Range
  .Collapse wdCollapseStart
   With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = sWord
      .Forward = True
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
    End With
    Do While .Find.Execute
      If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Do
      i = i + 1
    Loop
  End With
End With
Rng.Select
MsgBox "The word " & Chr(171) & sWord & Chr(187) & " occurred " & i & " times in the selected range.", _
  vbInformation, "word count"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why am i supposed to tell the script its out of range if it is out of range??? I'm searching inside selection already, why isn't Selection.Range enough? 

Either way it works now, huge thanks for the help!

Comment: «Why am i supposed to tell the script its out of range if it is out of range» You need to read the code more carefully. It does not tell you it's out of range. Rather, it tests whether what is found is *within* the selected range. If not, it exits the loop.

Comment: I understand that, my question is why am I even supposed to ask if it's in range or not? Why isn't using just selection.range enough? Why If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Do works??? Shouldn't the script that happens already inside of Selection.range check if it's still inside of Selection.range?

Comment: Because when a Find is successful, the Range moves to the found range. Consequently, the Find is no longer looking at your Selection; it's just looking for the next instance.